# Mathematica fails with boolean simplification with exponents

Tags: boolean-algebra, mathematica

I have a truly simple inequality, which I want to prove using Mathematica:

$$ a^x \geq 1 ,\quad \quad with \quad 1\leq a \quad and \quad 1\leq x \quad a,x  \in R$$

This is obviously true. When I try to solve this in Mathematica using for example:

```
Assuming[1 <= a && x >= 1, FullSimplify[a^x >= 1]]
```

the only output I get, is `a^x >= 1` and not the desired `True`. Is Mathematica really not able to solve this simple problem or am I missing something basic here?

Of course, my real inequality is much more complicated, but I broke it down until I identified working with exponents as the problem here.

Comment: Indeed it is strange that `FullSimplify[]` + `Assuming[]` fails here; however you might try `FullSimplify[Reduce[a^x >= 1 && a >= 1 && x >= 1, {a, x}], a >= 1 && x >= 1]` instead.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks, this works. Could you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `FullSimplify[]` accepts a second argument of constraints/assumptions, so `FullSimplify[a^x >= 1, 1 <= a && x >= 1]` would be a shorter way to write your snippet. That being said, one way that might work when the first one doesn't would be to use the function `Reduce[]` in tandem with `FullSimplify[]`; thus,

`FullSimplify[Reduce[a^x >= 1 && a >= 1 && x >= 1, {a, x}], a >= 1 && x >= 1]`

is one possible solution.